# Saving entity object in another's table column

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have email sending system which stores them at database and **CRON** is responsible for sending them. I wanted to save entities objects which needs to be included in this mail directly in email entity content column (*column type is object*).

I have query which takes partials from other entities, but **doctrine** saves different columns than I have requested for. This results in empty data in email.

I don't know if I explained myself clearly, if so I would answer any unclear points.

Email entity:

```
/**
 * Email
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="email")
 */
class Email
{
    const STATUS_WAITING = 'waiting';
    const STATUS_SENT = 'sent';
    const STATUS_FAILED = 'failed';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="language", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     */
    private $language;

    /**
     * @var text
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var object
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="object")
     */
    private $content;
}
```

Embedded email object with all necessary data **( THIS IS NOT ENTITY )**:

```
class BaseMail
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $from;

    /**
     * @var string from translation file
     */
    protected $subject;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $plainTemplate;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $htmlTemplate;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;

    public function __construct(array $options = array())
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }
}
```

Code:

```
$order = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')->findWithSomeUserPartialsFieldsAndRelations($id);
$email = new BaseEmail(array('object' => $order'));
$emailEntity = new Email();
$emailEntity->setContent($email);
```

And now even though `$order` has fields about `User` entity, they're not saved into email content column. So if I want to do something like that:

```
$order = $emailEntity->getContent()->getObject();
$userFirstName = $order->getUser()->getFirstname()
```

I get `NULL`

;

Comment: Post your code or no one can help you bro...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you choose the solution that will require serialize/deserialize an entity, but it doesn't recommended as common approach.

More info how to do it:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html

But instead of session you will store serialized entity to DB

The solution can bring you many bad surprises and be ready for a challenge .If you will go by this way I will recommend you to use JMSSerializationBundle https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle that have advanced methods to work with entity serialization.

Also do not forget "merge" entity after it was deserialized

Answer (score 0):

`@ORM\Column(type="object")` doesn't exist. You should create a relation between your two entites, exactly a `@ORM\ManyToOne()`

The only drawback is that, if the object changes between the mail creation and before the cron, the previous state of the object is not mantained, and the email could be generated wrong or with errors, if your logic depends on it.

Doctrine documentation about relation mapping: https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: well, this column type does exist... and the second class isn't entity. It's kinda like a value object.

Comment: You should make it an entity. Am entity IS a value object after all, and you need it persisted

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't solve the case and is not what I was asking about.

Comment: The only other possibility is to serialize the object and memorize it as a string. And it's not a really good thing to do.